# Seeking function or tool that will add vertices to polylines where endpoints are snapped to edges using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network, snapping, vertices

My friend and I are creating a walking network, and we have been having issues getting the routing to work. We just realized that the reason why our routes are messed up is because we snapped our routes to edges as well as endpoints. The routing works fine where the lines are snapped at endpoints because they share a common vertex, but when snapped to edges only one line has a vertex at that location, and the network doesn't see them as connected.

Is there a ArcMap tool or function that will automatically create a matching vertex on the other line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the licence level of your ArcMap, **Intersect** should work with a set tolerance.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000p000000.htm should create a new polyline with nodes where your vertices were.

You will need to rebuild your network afterwards