# Adding vertices (in QGIS) on segments where other nodes (from same layer) snap to it

Tags: qgis, intersection, routing, vertices

I've started drawing a routing network but realised after finishing it that it doesn't work without nodes at all intersections. "shortcut" lines were used to join the main routes together, and their end points are snapped to the segments (not vertices)

[image: Screenshot showing where I need to add vertices]

So to get the routing network to function properly I need to add vertices to these segments.

This appears to be similar to:

[Seeking function or tool that will add vertices to polylines where endpoints are snapped to edges using ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3565/is-there-a-function-or-tool-that-will-add-vertices-to-polylines-where-endpoints)

but I need a solution in QGIS.

Comment: Do you need any tools or do you want to do it manually?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it with a tool really, I know I could spend some time just moving around and manually creating vertices and snapping them to the end points but I thought there would be a way of doing it using some smarter way... (partly for saving the hassle and partly as an opportunity to learn a new tool). And I think for making these routing networks it could be pretty common that I'd need to add a load of these shortcuts and it would be great if I didn't have to manually add the vents each time.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS 3 open the processing toolbox and use either

- [Vector Overlay -> Line Intersections](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#line-intersections) to create a new point layer with the intersections between the two Polyline layers, or
- [Vector Overlay -> Split with lines](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#split-with-lines) to create vertices in the Input layer where it is intersected by the Split layer.

Comment: Thanks for your response, neither of these really do what I want though, Line intersections just adds a point layer which is not what I'm after. The second tool is closer to what I need (I had to duplicate the layer to use itself as an input) but still not what I'm hoping for. This splits the long segments into separate ones at the intersections. I'd like to be able to just add vertices to the segments where they are intersected.

Comment: @JdP Merge the lines after splitting: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#split-with-lines

Comment: @JdP You can also try writing a script in python using the QGIS API. It will not be easy the first time. https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/

Answer (score 0):

QGIS unfortunately does not support "add vertex to intersections". Arcmap has such a feature. I think you are doing a sequential process (draw 5-10 lines, then add corners, then draw 5-10 lines again and add corners..) I recommend you try the methods below.

- After installing QGIS with Grass; Try the "vertexadd" command in the "Tool" section in "Toolbox>GRASS>Vector>v.edit".
  https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/v.edit.html
- Try Plugins>Advanced Line Editor plugin (requires ogr)
- You can split the lines and merge with SAGA, but since this option is not very practical, it can be considered as the last option.